# Using Beamer, how do I make text appear on click and gray out afterwards?

Tags: beamer, pause, transparent

Using `\pause`, text appears on click but stays black afterwards.

Using `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`, text is gray before and afterwards.

How do I combine these effects, so the text is completely invisible before click but stays gray afterwards?

Comment: simply use a textcolor: `Same effect as the \pause\textcolor{black!20}{following command.} `

Answer (score 2):

`\uncover` is defined by

```
\newrobustcmd*{\uncover}{\alt{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}}
```

You want to make it really invisible before the slide it on, then fake invisible on current slide and covered in following slides. `\temporal` command is closest to your needs. But if we write

```
\newcommand{\myuncover}{\temporal{\beamer@reallymakeinvisible}{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}}
```

then `\myuncover<1>{...}` will give an error. So I define a new command `\mytemporal` similar to `\temporal` to make `<...>` work after `\myuncover`. Below is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=40}
\makeatletter
\protected\long\def\mytemporal#1#2#3<#4>{% past, present, future
  \gdef\beamer@doifnotinframe{\beamer@picked}\def\beamer@doifinframe{#2}%
  {\beamer@masterdecode{#4}%
  \ifbeamer@localanotherslide\gdef\beamer@picked{#1}\else\gdef\beamer@picked{#3}\fi}\beamer@donow}
\newcommand{\myuncover}{\mytemporal{\beamer@reallymakeinvisible}{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
  \myuncover<1>{test 1}
  \myuncover<2>{test 2}
  \myuncover<3>{test 3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]